# How to update a collection item without removing non existing values send on the query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Given this simple example, an item saved as:

```js
{
  "test": {
    "a1": "a1"
  }
}
```

When i call `collection.updateOne` with `$set` and the following object:
`await collection.updateOne(doc, {$set: {"test": {"a2": "a2"}}}, {upsert: true});`
it replaces the saved `test` object to:

```js
{
  "test": {
    "a2": "a2"
  }
}
```

The `a1` key will no longer exist as it also does not exist in the object sent.

I'm trying to update saved items with the values passed in the object **without ** removing non-existing values, I mean:
`{"test": {"a2": "a2"}}` would make the item be updated to:

```js
{
  "test": {
    "a1": "a1",
    "a2": "a2"
  }
}
```

I have written a function to recursively parse objects/arrays and build a query for this use case.

In my mind it looks like a mess and I'm not sure if it's correct:

```js
// The function attempts to parse arrays and objects recursively and recreate the query
function buildUpdateQuery(object, prefix = '') 
{
    let updateQuery = {};

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(object))
    {
        let newPrefix = prefix ? `${ prefix }.${ key }` : key;

        if (Array.isArray(value)) 
        {
            for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) 
            {
                let arrayPrefix = `${newPrefix}.${i}`;
                if (typeof value[i] === 'object' && value[i] !== null)
                    updateQuery = {...updateQuery, ...buildUpdateQuery(value[i], arrayPrefix)};
                else
                    updateQuery[arrayPrefix] = value[i];
            }
        }
        else if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null)
            updateQuery = {...updateQuery, ...buildUpdateQuery(value, newPrefix)};
        else
            updateQuery[newPrefix] = value;
    }

    return updateQuery;
}

export const set = async (req, res /*key, object*/) =>   // Using mongodb and express
{
    try
    {
        const [collection, key] = req.body.key.split("|");
        if (collection === undefined || key === undefined)
            return res ? res.send('fail') : 'fail'

        const doc = buildUpdateQuery(req.body.object);
        let r = await db.collection(collection).updateOne({ [key]: { $exists: true } }, { $set: doc }, { upsert: true });

        r = r.modifiedCount ? 'ok' : 'fail';
        return res ? res.send(r) : r
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.log(`\n[set]\n${ JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2) }\n\n`, error);
        return res ? res.send('fail') : 'fail'
    }
}
```

Calling the `set` function with:

```js
{"key": "vars|test", "object": {"test": {"a2": "a2"}}}
```

at `const doc = buildUpdateQuery(req.body.object);`

`doc` is `{test.a2: 'a2'}` and it indeed updates

`{"test": {"a1": "a1"}}` to `{"test": {"a1": "a1"},{"a2":"a2"}}`

I'm afraid it could mess up a collection at some time, maybe parsing something wrong.

I'm aware that i could first get the existing object with:

```js
const document = await db.collection(collection).findOne({ [key]: { $exists: true } });
```

and then modify it with the new values, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there any built-in method in **MongoDB** for such a thing?

If not, is the `buildUpdateQuery` correct or there's any other better approach for this use case?

Comment: If you set an object inside `$set` the DB object will be replaced but if you use dot notation you can append values to an existing object. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h3Q5rUvPnDh). Of course if key exists will be replaced, but if it doesn't it will be append.

Comment: I'm already doing this in the `buildUpdateQuery` function `let newPrefix = prefix ? ``${ prefix }.${ key }`` : key;` did you read the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `$set` stage as an aggregation pipeline stage you will get the desired result.

For example, given a document already in the database that you want to update:

```js
{
   test: {
      a1: "a1"
   }
}
```

You can issue an update with `{upsert: true}` to add the properties to the existing object or create a new one if there was no matching document found.

```js
await collection.updateOne({
  test: {
    a1: "a1"
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      test: {
        a2: "a2"
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  upsert: true
});
```

1. See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6RnnqAmbcYn) for an example of the update adding the properties to an existing matching object.
2. See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PGbDev2gFVC) for an example of the update creating a new object based on no matching document and `upsert: true` therefore becoming active.